# No temporary password in mysqld.log

Tags: passwords, centos7, temporary, mysql-5.7

I used mysql 5.7.16 community and centos 7.

I'm following a video [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2m3BM28Mz0) to install mysql:

1. wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-9.noarch.rpm
2. yum localinstall dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-9.noarch.rpm
3. yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
4. yum install mysql-community-server
5. service mysqld start

After starting mysql, I can see status is alive (running) with `service mysqld status`.

But I can' get anything by: `grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`

msyqld.log (ignore normal logs):

```
[Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist

[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

[Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/gtid_executed from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' doesn't exist

[Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.

[Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/server_cost from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.

[Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

[Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_leap_second from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.

[Warning] Can't open and lock time zone table: Table 'mysql.time_zone_leap_second' doesn't exist trying to live without them

[Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/servers from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.

[ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured this out.

1. I install centos 7 with mysql selected, mysql version is 5.5.
2. Remove it by: yum remove mysql-serverl.
3. Install 5.7.16 by this tutorial.
4. Has these error.
5. Yum remove mysql-community-server, install 5.7 again.
6. Still has these error.
7. Yum remove mysql-community-server, but delete dir /var/lib/mysql.
8. Then install again, it works.

The key point is need to remove /var/lib/mysql manually.

Comment: Thanks, removing `/var/lib/mysql` and reinstalling mysql did it for me!

Answer (score 8):

If there is no password, don't worry.
Do it.

> ```
> sudo mysql_secure_installation
> ```

just press the enter as you don't have password.

Comment: thanks  i thought Centos  7  would have  the  password as its in the same family with Fedora

Answer (score 7):

I simply restarted mysql and searched:

```
service mysqld start

grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Default password was displayed.

Comment: your solution is simple and work prefectly ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev | tr -d "."
```

`pwd` will be displayed after.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).